# BigQuery json function - cannot extract all values if json string not well formatted

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a json string stored in a field in BigQuery which has this structure::

```json
{'language': 'Eng', 'date_started': '2021-02-08 16: 56: 55 GMT', 'link_id': '111', 'url_variables': {'touchpoint': {'key': 'touchpoint', 'value': 'phone', 'type': 'url'
        }, 'interaction_id': {'key': 'interaction_id', 'value': '111', 'type': 'url'
        }
    }, 'ip_address': None, 'referer': '', 'user_agent': None, 'response_time': 111, 'data_quality': [], 'longitude': '', 'latitude': '', 'country': '', 'city': '', 'region': '', 'postal': '', 'dma': '', 'survey_data': {'25': {'id': 25, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'feedback_source', 'section_id': 1, 'shown': False
        }, '229': {'id': 229, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'recruitment_method', 'section_id': 1, 'shown': False
        }, '227': {'id': 227, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'meeting_point', 'section_id': 1, 'answer': 'phone', 'shown': True
        }, '221': {'id': 221, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'interaction_id', 'section_id': 1, 'answer': '222', 'shown': True
        }, '217': {'id': 217, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'session_id', 'section_id': 1, 'answer': '333', 'shown': True
        }, '231': {'id': 231, 'type': 'ESSAY', 'question': 'BlaBla question 4', 'section_id': 3, 'answer': 'Bla Bla answer', 'shown': True
        }, '255': {'id': 255, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'tz_offset', 'section_id': 3, 'answer': '-120', 'shown': True
        }, '77': {'id': 77, 'type': 'parent', 'question': 'Bla Bla 1', 'section_id': 35, 'options': {'10395': {'id': 10395, 'option': 'Neutraal', 'answer': '3'
                }
            }, 'shown': True
        }, '250': {'id': 250, 'type': 'RADIO', 'question': 'Bla Bla?', 'section_id': 66, 'original_answer': '1', 'answer': '1', 'answer_id': 10860, 'shown': True
        }, '251': {'id': 251, 'type': 'RADIO', 'question': 'Bla Bla', 'section_id': 66, 'original_answer': '0', 'answer': '0', 'answer_id': 10863, 'shown': True
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to extract some of the values with the query below, but I cannot extract *response_time* or any of the values inside the *survey_data* structure.
They always come out as null.

```sql
DECLARE resp STRING 
DEFAULT "{'id': '111', 'contact_id': '', 'status': 'Complete', 'is_test_data': '0', 'date_submitted': '2021-07-08 17: 02: 16 GMT', 'session_id': '111', 'language': 'Eng', 'date_started': '2021-02-08 16: 56: 55 GMT', 'link_id': '111', 'url_variables': {'touchpoint': {'key': 'touchpoint', 'value': 'phone', 'type': 'url' }, 'interaction_id': {'key': 'interaction_id', 'value': '111', 'type': 'url' } }, 'ip_address': None, 'referer': '', 'user_agent': None, 'response_time': 111, 'data_quality': [], 'longitude': '', 'latitude': '', 'country': '', 'city': '', 'region': '', 'postal': '', 'dma': '', 'survey_data': {'25': {'id': 25, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'feedback_source', 'section_id': 1, 'shown': False }, '229': {'id': 229, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'recruitment_method', 'section_id': 1, 'shown': False }, '227': {'id': 227, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'meeting_point', 'section_id': 1, 'answer': 'phone', 'shown': True }, '221': {'id': 221, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'interaction_id', 'section_id': 1, 'answer': '222', 'shown': True }, '217': {'id': 217, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'session_id', 'section_id': 1, 'answer': '333', 'shown': True }, '231': {'id': 231, 'type': 'ESSAY', 'question': 'BlaBla question 4', 'section_id': 3, 'answer': 'Bla Bla answer', 'shown': True }, '255': {'id': 255, 'type': 'TEXTBOX', 'question': 'tz_offset', 'section_id': 3, 'answer': '-120', 'shown': True }, '77': {'id': 77, 'type': 'parent', 'question': 'Bla Bla 1', 'section_id': 35, 'options': {'10395': {'id': 10395, 'option': 'Neutraal', 'answer': '3' } }, 'shown': True }, '250': {'id': 250, 'type': 'RADIO', 'question': 'Bla Bla?', 'section_id': 66, 'original_answer': '1', 'answer': '1', 'answer_id': 10860, 'shown': True }, '251': {'id': 251, 'type': 'RADIO', 'question': 'Bla Bla', 'section_id': 66, 'original_answer': '0', 'answer': '0', 'answer_id': 10863, 'shown': True } } }";

SELECT
  JSON_VALUE( resp, '$.url_variables.interaction_id.value') as url_interaction_id_value ,
  JSON_VALUE( resp, '$.url_variables.interaction_id.type') as url_interaction_id_type,
  JSON_VALUE( resp, '$.language') as language,
  JSON_QUERY( resp, '$.response_time') as response_time, -- NOT WORKING
  JSON_QUERY( resp, '$.survey_data') as survey_data -- NOT WORKING
```

[image]

I tried with jq in bash from the CLI and it seems to complain about the fact that some of the **None** values are not quoted.

**Question:**
Does it mean that BigQuery attempts to extract values from the JSON string as far as it can, "until" it encounters something that it is not well formatted (e.g. the unquoted None values) and then it just cannot parse further and returns nulls ?

NB: In another app, I have been able to parse the json file in Python and extract values from inside the json string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have few formatting issues with your `resp` field which you can fix with few `REPLACE`s as in below example

```
SELECT
  JSON_VALUE( resp, '$.url_variables.interaction_id.value') as url_interaction_id_value ,
  JSON_VALUE( resp, '$.url_variables.interaction_id.type') as url_interaction_id_type,
  JSON_VALUE( resp, '$.language') as language,
  JSON_QUERY( resp, '$.response_time') as response_time, -- WORKING NOW
  JSON_QUERY( resp, '$.survey_data') as survey_data -- WORKING NOW,
FROM (
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(resp, "None,", "'None',"), "True", "true"), "False", "false") as resp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - now it gets you all you need

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, actually a colleague pointed me to this direction, but your answer came first :-)
Is it stated anywhere which kind of JSON parser BigQuery is using? 
It could be useful to know so to produce compatible JSON strings at the source. (In this case we are not in control of the JSON source though)